# Writing file as JSON using NLog in a programmatic way

Tags: c#, json, logging, nlog

I would like write a file as JSON using NLog. I am aware it can be done this way.

```xml
<target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logFileNamePrefix}.json">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
       <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
       <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
       <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
</target>
```

But I would like to do it in my C# code. I started with this:

```
  var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

  var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
  string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

  string fullPath = Path.Combine(folder, "mylog.json");
  fileTarget.FileName = fullPath;

  config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);        
  var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, fileTarget);
  config.LoggingRules.Add(fileRule);           

  LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

but It only write it as file but not a JSON. Any help or hint will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might be missing your layout.  This works

```
var fileTarget = new FileTarget()
{
    Name = "JSonTarget",
    FileName = @"C:\Temp\Json.txt"
};

var JSLayout = new JsonLayout();
JSLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("time", "${longdate}"));
JSLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("level", "${level:upperCase=true}"));
JSLayout.Attributes.Add(new JsonAttribute("message", "${message}"));

fileTarget.Layout = JSLayout;

var JSonTargetRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);

LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("JSonTarget", fileTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(JSonTargetRule);

LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

var _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

_logger.Info("JSON Informational Message");
_logger.Debug("JSON Debug Message");
```